# Proxy to redirect DNS during development

Tags: windows, linux, android-development

I am using [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) to test an app. The app is basically a browser that connects to my website. I do not have the app's source.
I do the development and testing of the website in a domain like this: dev.mywebsite.com

The app connects to mywebsite.com. Genymotion allows me to use an HTTP proxy. My question is, is there any software for windows or linux that would work as a proxy and redirect all requests to mywebsite.com to dev.mywebsite.com ?

Comment: Is your dev website on the same ip address?  If not, an entry in your hosts file might do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the classic purpose of using a hosts file. It's a very simple to edit file wherein you can put manual overrides for domain names to force them to resolve to some given IP.

---

### Windows

Here's a simple tutorial on how to edit your windows hosts file: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

Example of windows hosts file (C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts):

```
102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host
```

In the windows host file you can see the `#` mark identifying the start of a comment which is ignored by the OS.

---

### Linux

Here's the linux man page for the linux /etc/hosts file which is nigh identical to the windows hosts file, examples at the bottom of the man page make fairly clear how it works: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/hosts.5.html

Example of linux /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.1.10    foo.mydomain.org       foo
192.168.1.13    bar.mydomain.org       bar
146.82.138.7    master.debian.org      master
209.237.226.90  www.opensource.org
```

The linux host file also recognizes the `#` as beginning of comments just the same as the windows file.

Comment: Thanks, although this works when I type the address in my browser (I see my dev site content) it does not seem to work inside Genymotion, which uses virtual box. It seems it's bypassing the hosts file somehow

Comment: @Cornwell It's probably not bypassing the hosts file, your issue is most likely that you need to edit the hosts file on that other machine. You must realize the hosts file only forces DNS resolution overrides for the OS that you make those edits on, each OS install will need it's own hosts file updates that you want to override this resolution with.